# date format when I make an sql in aggregations - mongodb - pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pyspark

I've to make a sql with aggregation from a field (date) with this format:

```
executionDate: 2022-08-22T22:15:55.383+00:00
```

The value of this field always ends with "+00:00"

I tried to execute the below aggregation but it' doesn't work:

```
'executionDate': {
      '$lte': datetime.strptime("2022-08-22T22:15:55.383+00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"[:-3]+"00:00"), 
      '$gte': datetime.strptime("2022-08-22T22:15:55.383+00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"[:-3]+"00:00") 
}
```

And with this sql

```
{'$match': {'$and': [{'executionDate': {'$gte': datetime.strptime("2022-09-22T22:17:55.383+00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00") }}, ....
```

I've this error,

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid Aggregation map Map(uri -> mongodb://localhost:27017, database -> entity, collection -> status, pipeline -> [{'$match': {'$and': [{'executeDate': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 22, 22, 17, 55, 383000)}}]):%njava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid pipeline option: [{'$match': {'$and': [{'executeDate': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 22, 22, 17, 55, 383000)}}, It should be a list of pipeline stages (Documents) or a single pipeline stage (Document)
```

Comment: "but it' doesn't work" ... What doesn't work?  Is there an error? ... You don't receive the expected output? ...?

Comment: this is what I have to write in the sql, '$lte': datetime(2022, 10, 8, 13, 20, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc). I use python to make aggregations, but if i make the sql in mongodb it doesn't work

Comment: If you show all the relevant code, any error messages, the expected output, and the actual output, it would be easier for readers to understand the issue(s).

Comment: Have you tried `datetime.fromisoformat("2022-08-22T22:15:55.383+00:00")`?

Comment: yes, and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If we add '$date' in json format and convert date to isoformat, it works!

```
from_date = datetime(2022, 8, 22, 22, 35, 33, 804, pytz.timezone('Europe / Berlin'))            
from_date = from_date.isoformat()
        
{'$match': {'$and': [{'executionDate': {'$lte': {'$date': from_date}, ....
```